# PHP not loading extensions

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I have am running a local server with PHP 5.3.6, and Apache 2.2.19 running on Ubuntu 11.03. I build both Apache and PHP from source. PHP is working fine with Apache, however it seems to never load any extensions. I have uncommented the ones I want PHP to load, I have checked that PHP is reading the INI file, I have uncommented the `extension_dir` directive and made sure it was correct.

The files `mysqli.so` and `mysql.so` seems to be missing, with a lot of other files too. This was my first time installing PHP from source. I am aware that PHP 5.3.6 does not bundle the MySQL client libraries.

I also checked the PHP repository, and it is no longer maintained. I could use PDO, but I much prefer using the MySQL class.

My question is: Where do I get these files from? I have checked the MySQL site, and it doesn't really help me. PHP only seems to be loading the extensions that are already built into PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL extensions come in separate packages:

```
$ apt-cache search mysql |grep php
```

This is what I have on debian (and it worked automatically after installing it via apt-get):

```
plaes@machine:~$ dpkg -L php5-mysql
/.
/etc
/etc/php5
/etc/php5/conf.d
/etc/php5/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini
/etc/php5/conf.d/mysqli.ini
/etc/php5/conf.d/mysql.ini
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/php5
/usr/lib/php5/20090626
/usr/lib/php5/20090626/mysqli.so
/usr/lib/php5/20090626/pdo_mysql.so
/usr/lib/php5/20090626/mysql.so
/usr/share/doc/php5-mysql
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply pleas. I should have mentioned this, but I did try installing it this way, but it never worked. Where does it put the file once you have downloaded it?

Comment: I am going to move the so files that are in there into the directory it is reading from. I will then tell you if it worked or not. Thanks plaes.

Comment: I made a copy of mysql.so and placed it in /usr/local/php-5.3.6/ext. I did a server restart, but it still has not loaded it.

Comment: Did you edit appropriate php.ini and add extension=mysql.so ?

Comment: Yes, I edited it. It is uncommented. I also checked the extension_dir, and the value is "./ext", which I assume is correct. Is there any sort of main path for PHP? Or will it automatically read from its root folder?

Comment: You can get extension_dir using phpinfo();

Comment: Yes... that is where I got the value of `extension_dir` from.

Comment: Hum.. I'm now all out of ideas :S

Comment: I simply used the full path for the extension, and that worked. Thank you for telling me where I could obtain these files. I can finally get some sleep.

Comment: You will run into serious problems when Ubuntu updates its PHP packages, and you don't.

Answer (score 1):

## Missing extension .so files

The extensions listed and commented out in `php.ini` are just examples. They are not "delivered"/installed with PHP by default.
Also, there is no `mysql.so` file unless you built the extension as a "shared" extension.

If you compile PHP yourself, you need to activate the extensions in the configuration. Run `./configure --help` to get the options.

If you change the configuration with the configure script, you need to re-make it of course (make && make install).

## configure: error: Cannot find MySQL header files under /usr/share/mysql.

Install the `libmysqlclient-dev` package or use mysqlnd: `--with-mysql=mysqlnd` (same for mysqli and pdo-mysql config parameters)

Use `dpkg -L libmysqlclient-dev` to find the location and pass that, or leave the path empty in the configuration parameter.

## Compiling it yourself

You don't seem to know much about compiling code yourself, so the question is if your really need it.

Ask yourself the question *why* you are compiling it yourself.

Check the weight of it against the problems you have when not using the stock packages from ubuntu:

- you need to install all the devel package
- upgrading has to be done manually, and the package manager won't do it for you

Comment: When you've changed the configuration, do you have to remake it? Do I run make and make install?

Comment: This is the error I get:
configure: error: Cannot find MySQL header files under /usr/share/mysql.
Note that the MySQL client library is not bundled anymore!

I also tried these locations:
/usr/bin/mysql /etc/mysql /usr/lib/mysql /usr/share/mysql

Comment: "This was my first time installing PHP from source."

Comment: Installing that still has not solved the issue.