# Why does IIS PHP not recognize PhpRedis when it exists and is added correctly?

Tags: windows, php, iis, redis

Before you read:

- [PHP not loading extensions](https://serverfault.com/questions/298765/php-not-loading-extensions) does not answer my question because I do not have Apache. I have IIS.
- [MySQL extension of PHP not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/404301/mysql-extension-of-php-not-working) does not answer my question because the files have the same permissions as all other DLL files and have not broken inheritance.
- [PHP on IIS doesn't load sqlsrv extension](https://serverfault.com/questions/841901/php-on-iis-doesnt-load-sqlsrv-extension) does not answer my question because the item is for the latest version.

I currently have a PHP script which simply adds Redis (using PhpRedis).

```php
<?php
    $redis = new Redis ();
?>
```

This creates a "500 Internal Server Error" message. Upon inspecting PHP 7.4 x64's logs, [despite being located here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP4Ce.png), loading the page triggers the error:

```
[06-Aug-2021 15:54:13 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_redis.dll' (tried: C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.4\ext\php_redis.dll (The specified module could not be found.), C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.4\ext\php_php_redis.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

It is not searching in the wrong place or not added because of these entries in `php.ini`:

```
[WebPIChanges]
extension_dir="C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.4\ext\"
...
[ExtensionList]
extension=php_redis.dll
...
```

IIS *can* detect the redis plugin in the extension manager and states that it is enabled.

This issue occurs in v7.4. I have tried this in v8.0, and I still face the same issues. PhpRedis 5.3.4 provides a v7.4 DLL, still the same issue with no dependencies made aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. My compiled version of PHP did not support thread safety features, therefore I must either compile a version with thread safety or use the NTS version of PhpRedis.